# Flows: trouble with updating a field used in a formula used in a validation rule

Tags: visual-workflow, formula-field, validation-rule, field-update

I am using an object from a third party package, we'll call it `xyz__Obj__c`, that has several fields, let's call them `xyz__A__c`, `xyz__B__c` and `xyz__C__c`, that are percentages. The package then has a formula field, let's call it `xyz__Total__c` that is the sum of these percentages (with a simple `xyz__A__c + xyz__B__c + xyz__C__c`). This total must equal 100, which is checked in the third party package using a validation rule against `xyz__Total__c`.

In our use case we don't care about these fields and wanted to create a simple autolaunched flow that, on creation of an `xyz__Obj__c` record, simply sets the field `xyz__A__c` value to the literal 100.

Unfortunately, it seems that field updates in flows don't cause re-evaluation of formula fields in the same record. I say this because the validation rule against `xyz__Total__c` is being violated and we get the validation rule's message presented when trying to save a record created through the Salesforce UI.

We have tried:

- a flow: the validation rule is violated
- a process builder flow: the validation rule is violated
- a trigger: all is fine

According to the [official documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm), flows are processed before triggers...

Anyone seen this before? If so, did you find a non-trigger solution? (The nice thing about flow-based automation is that even when packaged they can still be disabled on a subscriber org if a customer needs to do something different.)

Comment: What if you explicitly set the B and C fields to zero?

Comment: Thanks @DavidCheng, I'll give it a go, though whilst these fields don't have default values I can successfully save the record if I manually set just this one field to 100 through the form before saving the new record.

Comment: yes it seems unlikely that zero will make a difference.  You say you're using an auto-launched Flow - what happens if instead you use a process builder to set field A on creation?

Comment: @DavidCheng explicitly setting zero for the other fields didn't change anything. As to using process builder, just trying out that suggestion.

Comment: @DavidCheng process builder suffers the same issue here.

Comment: Just verified that doing the same logic in a trigger works. Unfortunately using a trigger is not ideal since it would go in a package and we would need to add settings to allow it to be disabled...

Answer (score 1):

It turned out to be a logic issue in the flow, before the assignment, that did not cause an error to be shown but prevented the assignment happening. Once fixed we found that the flow's change to the field was reflected correctly in the formula field used in the validation rule.

Still, not sure why the process builder variant didn't work since this used an "always" condition and a straight forward setting of a field value.

The learning points were:

- flow changes to fields do get reflected in formulae
- flow error handling isn't very good
- debugging flows on record creation doesn't really work